# What kind of file type to use for music file

Tags: android, xml

[image]

Hi. I am new in android. I want to upload a music file to raw folder. But I do not know what kind of file should I use. It gives error when I drag and drop the file to the raw folder.

Comment: That file has illegal characters in its name. Please rename the file to something simpler, like `song.mp3`.

Comment: it still shows the same

Comment: What is the error? If you are referring to that dialog box, that is not an error. Android Studio is asking you how to handle MP3 files. I would choose the bottom radio button, to open the file in the associated application, since MP3 is not text that Android Studio can edit.

Comment: Use only lowercase and only `_` for separation, no `-`